Migrate data from Confluent Kafka to Bitnami Kafka
We have a very old version of Confluent Kafka running on our kubernetes cluster, cp-kafka:5.4.1 and we are now moving to the bitnami kafka latest version. How can I migrate all my data from my old Kafka installation to the new one?
I tried running mirror maker in a docker container on the same cluster but the mirror maker does not copy the data nor it shows any logs. I am using Mirror Maker from Kafka 2.8.1. When I try to run Mirror Maker to copy data from one confluent kafka installation to another it works but does not work with Bitnami Kafka.
Is it possible to migrate data from Confluent Kafka to Bitnami Kafka using Mirror Maker? If not, what is the correct way to do it?

I would not recommend mirroring data for the purposes of migration. You can backup your StatefulSets, the swap the image tags for the corresponding Apache Kafka release from Bitnami, then upgrade like normal following the Kafka documentation
There's no structural log difference since Confluent is still using Apache Kafka
